# How do I put a normal title bar on this child window?

Tags: x11

So I understand that XWindow is changing the title bar based on it being a child window. Can I override this? Sample program:

```
/*
 * Study for child windows.
 */
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

Display* d;

int main(void) {

    Window       w, w2;
    XEvent       e;
    const char*  msg = "Hello, window 1";
    const char*  msg2 = "Hello, window 2";
    int          s;
    int          x;
    GC           gracxt;
 
    d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    if (d == NULL) {

        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open display\n");
        exit(1);

    }
 
    s = DefaultScreen(d);
    gracxt = XDefaultGC(d, s);

    w = XCreateSimpleWindow(d, RootWindow(d, s), 10, 10, 640, 480, 5,
                            BlackPixel(d, s), WhitePixel(d, s));
    XSelectInput(d, w, ExposureMask|KeyPressMask|PointerMotionMask|StructureNotifyMask);
    XMapWindow(d, w);

    w2 = XCreateSimpleWindow(d, w, 100, 100, 100, 100, 5,
                            BlackPixel(d, s), WhitePixel(d, s));
    XSelectInput(d, w2, ExposureMask|KeyPressMask|PointerMotionMask|StructureNotifyMask);
    XMapWindow(d, w2);

    while (1) {

        XNextEvent(d, &e);
        if (e.type == Expose) {

            if (e.xany.window == w) XDrawString(d, e.xany.window, gracxt, 10, 50, msg, strlen(msg));
            else XDrawString(d, e.xany.window, gracxt, 10, 50, msg2, strlen(msg2));

        }
        if (e.type == KeyPress) break; /* exit on any key */

    }

    XCloseDisplay(d);

    return 0;

}
```

[image]

The resulting child window looses its title bar, but gains a black outline frame. What I want in this case is just a window in window, IE., with title frame, size bars, etc.

Is there a method to get this behavior?

What is the purpose? This is for "multiple document" type interfaces, where the user gets several documents contained within the parent window, but can move and size each one within the window.

OS is Ubuntu 20.04, Window manager is Gnome/GDM3.

Thanks.

Scott Franco
San Jose, CA

Comment: The title bar and decorations belong to the window manager.  It's not a part of X.  You'll need to check into the window manager you're using.

Comment: So just to nail this to the ground, I would need to draw my own frames on the child windows and handle size/move with the mouse? I can do that, but the biggest problem then would be if a different window manager were used, the child windows with frames would then look different from other windows.

Comment: Child windows do not ordinarily have title bars.  Child windows are used for buttons and text boxes and such, not for top level windows.

Comment: In windows, the mode is used for "multiple document interface", it is where you have multiple subwindows inside the parent window, each of which is positionable and sizable. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-the-multiple-document-interface.

Comment: Yes, but even Microsoft stopped recommending MDI 20 years ago because it was too confusing for users.  In any case, that's not part of X.  Most X apps use some additional framework (Qt, wxWidgets) that can provide some of the decorations for you.